# How to use functions from Woocommerce documentation?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to use [this](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_api_ordersdelete_order/) function from Woocommerce docs. I don't know how to make a functional code. This is what I got

```
function my_woo_delete_order($id, $force) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $array =  WC()->api->WC_API_Orders->delete_order($id, $force); 
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    print "</pre>";
}

my_woo_delete_order(1234, true);
```

but It throughs an error:

*Notice: Undefined property: WC_API::$WC_API_Orders in [that line]*

Comment: it's not a static method, you need to call it from an instance. try `WC()->api->WC_API_Orders->delete_order(`...

Comment: @mmm I have edited my function as you suggested but still with an error `Notice: Undefined property: WC_API::$WC_API_Orders in...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// define the woocommerce_api_delete_order callback 
function action_woocommerce_api_delete_order( $id, $instance ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_api_delete_order', 'action_woocommerce_api_delete_order', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I simple don't know what to do with a code you have suggested :-)